# Angular 6: Loading csv from local in application

Tags: angular, angular6

I am trying to load a csv file that i kept in asset folder. And no matter what i do, its always throwing error. However if i try fetching this file manually(`http://localhost:4201/assets/states.csv`), i am able to do this.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.http
      .get("/assets/states.csv")
      .pipe(
        map((res: any) => res.json())
      )
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
      });
  }
```

Error:

```
core.js:1673 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:4201/assets/states.csv", ok: false, …}
```

Its even showing status 200 but i wonder by in Error mode.

Comment: are you using `httpClientModule` ?

Comment: Can you add error details? From network tab ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `{responseType: 'text'}`

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.http
      .get("/assets/states.csv", {responseType: 'text'})
      .pipe(
         map((res: any) => res.json())
      )
      .subscribe(data => {
         console.log(data);
      });
}
```

You need to inform Angular that you are expecting the response as *text*.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are  using the new `HttpClientModule`  then you will have to set the `responseType` to `'text'`, otherwise the HttpClient  would try to interpret the content as json and raise a SyntaxError...

```
this.http.get('assets/file.csv', {responseType: 'text'})
    .subscribe(
        data => {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error => {
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
```